# Process to generate API documentation

Tags: java, eclipse, documentation, javadoc

How can I generate the API documentation for a certain project?
What do I need exactly? javadoc plugin? rt.jar?
Could anyone describe the whole process?

Right now, I am stucked here:
I have documented all my classes and methods with javadoc comments. When I try in Eclipse:
Project - Generate Javadoc -> Javadoc Command -> Configure -> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
and I CAN´T FIND javadoc.exe!

Is javadoc.exe included with the jre7?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: sorry, Eclipse. edited.

Answer (score 3):

Javadoc is not part of the JRE, but of the JDK.

Comment: @capovawi You need a Java Development Kit (JDK) install rather than just the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). The JDK includes a JRE plus a java compiler and the javadoc tool and many other things. You can download a JDK [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Comment: is there any way to add that functionality to the JRE without installing the JDK?